# Register basket calculation result view

Tags: calculation, intershop

We are trying to implement our own custom basket calculation rule set and register new result view to get basket calculation results, but we are unable to find some info how to register new result view class?

We are using examples from here: https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/23V395#Cookbook-BasketCalculation-Recipe:TheResultView

And problem is, how to use/register "TutorialCalculationResultView" class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a factory class which creates the result view:

```
public class TutorialCalculationResultViewFactoryImpl implements CalculationResultViewFactory
{
    @Override
    public LineItemCtnrCalculationResultView createCalculationResultView(BaseCalculationResultView view)
    {
        return new TutorialCalculationResultView(view);
    }
}
```

Then this implementation needs to be wired via the component framework:

```
<implementation name="TutorialCalculationResultViewFactory" implements="CalculationResultViewFactory"
                class="yourPackageName.TutorialCalculationResultViewFactoryImpl" />
```

Finally you have to register an instance of this class as described in the cookbook:

```
<fulfill requirement="assignment" of="BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionFactory">
    <instance with="CalculationResultViewFactoryAssignment">
        <fulfill requirement="ruleSetID" value="yourPackageName.TutorialRuleSet" />
        <fulfill requirement="factory">
            <instance with="TutorialCalculationResultViewFactory" />
        </fulfill>
    </instance>
</fulfill>
```

Comment: Thank you, but should TutorialCalculationResultView then extends LineItemCtnrCalculationResultView? Because I don't need all methods from LineItemCtnrCalculationResultView interface.

Comment: I think it has to, or else it won't fit the return type of the `CalculationResultViewFactory` interface. However, your `TutorialCalculationResultView` can just inherit from an existing result view (e. g. `NetBasedLineItemCtnrCalculationResultView_V3`), so you don't need to implement all the methods.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answer, you can then access the view using this extension:

```
TutorialCalculationResultView view = basketbo.getExtension(BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtension.class);
```

this should return your result view.

Comment: Thank you, but as I sad above, I just need to add 4 new calculated values on line items and 2 on basket (totals), I don't need 50 methods from LineItemCtnrCalculationResultView :) Is that possible?

Comment: i updated to make it clearer, that should return your result view implementation that is based on LineItemCtnrCalculationResultView.

Comment: Ok, but if i implement LineItemCtnrCalculationResultView (also createCalculationResultView method from CalculationResultViewFactory requires that) I have to implement 50 not needed methods. For example, we need to add "getMonthlyPrice", "getMonthlyDiscount", "getUpfrontDiscount" and "getUpfrontPrice", and only that methods to our result view.

Comment: basketbo.getExtension(BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtension.class) returns com.intershop.sellside.appbase.b2c.internal.calculation.BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionImpl and not TutorialCalculationResultView :( I see that TutorialCalculationResultView is "_delegate" field in BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionImpl but I can't use methods from TutorialCalculationResultView.

Comment: Ah i see, BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionImpl extends LineItemCtnrCalculationResultViewProxy which then implements LineItemCtnrCalculationResultView. I see that _delegate is protected, so if you replace BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionImpl with your own class that inherits BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionImpl then u can access it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I need to register new custom calculation extension on BasketBO with component framework?

Comment: Indeed this is what u have to do. I am however doubting now if there isn't an easier solution to this problem. Maybe good to check this with support.

Comment: Ok, I opened another question just for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456891/how-to-call-custom-methods-from-calculationresultview-class