# How to call custom methods from CalculationResultView class

Tags: calculation, intershop

We implemented custom calculation view class with custom methods e.g. "getMonthlyDiscount", "getMonthlyPrice", etc. and registered it with component framework to BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionFactory. The problem is we are unable to find information of how to call those methods to get calculated results.

By calling "basketbo.getExtension(BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtension.class)" we get "BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionImpl", so only methods defined in "LineItemCtnrCalculationResultViewProxy" are available, not our custom.

The same example can be applied to question of how to call method "getDuties" from TutorialCalculationResultView given here: https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/23V395#Cookbook-BasketCalculation-Recipe:TheResultView

Thank you for your answers!
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Willem's answer:

If you're using an ICM version >= 7.10.8.0 you should be able to retrieve your `TutorialCalculationResultView` via:

```
LineItemCtnrCalculationResultViewProxy resultViewProxy = basketBO.getExtension("CalculationResultView");
TutorialCalculationResultView resultView = (TutorialCalculationResultView)resultViewProxy.getDelegate();
```

If you're using a version before 7.10.8.0 and have an Intershop support contract, you could always try asking Intershop tech support if this feature could be downported.

Alternatively, if the custom methods in your `TutorialCalculationResultView` are simple and only pass through the values of the associated `CalculationRuleSet`, then you can also use one of the following methods from the `BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtension` to retrieve the value directly:

```
// returns a single item from the group
ComputedItem getComputedItem(String group, String id);
// returns the whole group
Collection<ComputedItem> getComputedItems(String group);
```

Comment: Yes, we are using 7.10.7.3 but if this is possible with latest 7.10.9.1 we'll upgrade and try with first approach. Thank you, I'll mark answer as accepted as soon as I try that.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the magic happens in this instance:

```
<instance name="BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionFactory" 
              with="BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionFactoryImpl" > ..</>
```

This `BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionFactory` creates the `BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionImpl` instances. It is hardcoded so u cant replace this with your own implementation sadly.

So the only option i see is to replace the whole `BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionFactory` factory.

```
<implementation name="BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionFactoryImpl" 
                implements="BusinessObjectExtensionFactory" 
                class="your.custom.cartridge.MyBasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionFactory">                  
    <requires name="assignment" contract="CalculationResultViewFactoryAssignment" cardinality="0..n" />
</implementation>
```

`MyBasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionFactory` can then extend `BasketBOCalculationResultViewExtensionFactory` and you have to override the methods `addAssignment` and `createExtension`